# Sampling distribution of the Score statistics of a GLM MODEL

Tags: generalized-linear-model, likelihood, asymptotics, fisher-information

In the context of a GLM (with a distribution that belongs to the exponential family), we often compute the score statistics
$$
U = \frac{\partial LogLike(\boldsymbol{\beta};\mathbf{y})}{\partial\boldsymbol{\beta} }
$$
and we say that it is distributed, asymptotically, as a multivariate normal with zero mean vector and covariance matrix given by the Fisher information.

My question is: Why is it normally distributed? How can I see/prove it?

Comment: Can you write it as a sum of iid terms?

Comment: Yes, if you assume independence between observations

Comment: Since independence is an assumption of GLM, that's easy. So now apply CLT.